# Convert b64 to binary and run attached to Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to follow the example found here:

https://truesecdev.wordpress.com/2016/03/15/embedding-exe-files-into-powershell-scripts/

**What code does:** `convert a base64 string to a binary file and execute/load it into the Powershell process.`

**What I'm trying to achieve:** `avoid the executable being written to the disk, this way the exe is executed only in the memory and not maintain a copy saved somewhere.`

I got the function Invoke-ReflectivePEInjection from:

https://github.com/PowerShellMafia/PowerSploit/blob/master/CodeExecution/Invoke-ReflectivePEInjectio....

This is my current script:

```
https://codeshare.io/5PbrJY
```

I can't past the script here because it exceeds the characters limit.

When I run the script i got a lot of errors like:

https://pastebin.com/rtB9hP13

I have uploaded the error log here ^ (cant past it here as it exceed the character limit)

Looking for any kind of help on it.

Comment: Did you replace the `$InputString` value with your own base64-encoded binary before running?

Comment: Yes, i do have replaced it.

Comment: To give this a look I tried using the `Invoke-ReflectivePEInjection` function but Windows Defender immediately blocked it as a known threat "Trojan:PowerShell/Powersploit.J" so even if you get your code working you'll likely run into problems using it unfortunately.

Comment: @Caio Can you show us _the very first_ error it throws? Please add to your post as text (not screenshots)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen i have added to the post.